# How to change colors of function plots in Tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to compare different learning-rate-decays using Tensorflow. Therefore I visualize the cost functions in Tensorboard ('EVENTS'-tab). My problem is that the different plots of the functions are in very similar colors making it hard to compare them. Is there any possibility to change those colors?

Comment: After digging a bit into the code when I had the same issues, I think there is no easy way to change the colors. As far as I understood it, the colors are randomly chosen among 16 and whitened/darkened when two plots have the same color but I found some kind of correlation between similar names which made it difficult to visualize plots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's currently no way to change those colors, but a recent release has made the colors more differentiated. Try updating and seeing if that helps.

Comment: How about editing this post and refer to George's solution?

Answer (score 10):

Just create different summary writes with different log files for each learning rate. Then launch the tensorboard tool using:
`tensorboard --logdir=tag1:/path/to/summary/one,tag2:/path/to/summary/two`

Comment: Nice and clean solution!

Comment: How does this help? I've tried muliple ways of grouping the summary files without getting a good color assignment (without running one tensorboard per group)

Comment: Thanks for great solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is very far from an actual solution, but in case someone only wants to change the colors for a screenshot in a paper or presentation its a quick workaround:

1. Open your browser dev tools (F12)
2. Search for the color code you want to change (the default orange is #ff7043) and replace it with the color you want

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/893#issuecomment-377063653), creating (and pointing tensorboard to) a symlink of a run's logdir is one workaround to change the color used to plot that run.